# Save sparkR dataframe with HiveContext using saveAsTable command

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

How to save sparkR data frame when working with HiveContext using saveAsTable command

```
df_5 <- loadDF(sqlContext, "Report02_cashier_Hourly_total_Trans_july30.parquet", "parquet")  /*I loaded the parquet file as dataframe*/
sqlContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc) /*Initialized the hive context*/

sql(sqlContext, "create table Report2_cashier_hourly (location_code INT, business_date DATE, cashier STRING, hour STRING, store_no STRING, region STRING, city STRING, zone STRING, Total_trans INT)") /*created a table Report2_cashier_hourly*/
```

How to use `saveAsTable(df, tableName, source, mode, ...)` to save the `df_5(data frame)` into a hive table `Report02_cashier_hourly`.

Comment: Kindly refer for answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129835/loading-sparkr-data-frame-in-hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129835/loading-sparkr-data-frame-in-hive)